# System.IndexOutOfRangeException on SqlDataReader.get_Item() only when using alias

Tags: c#, sql

I have a sql query that I am creating and running through C# code using SqlDataReader.  The query is quite simple, it amounts to:

`SELECT colName1 AS altColName1, colName2 AS altColName2 FROM table`.

When I run the query in SQL Server Management Studio it works and gives the expected results.

Additionally, when I run the simpler query:

`SELECT colName1, colName2 FROM table`

using the SqlDataReader it works fine, except obviously I don't get the aliases.

The problem is, when using SqlDataReader and giving it the first query, I get:

`System.IndexOutOfRangeException -- colName1`

I'm perplexed since obviously that index works fine without the alias attached.  Am I doing something wrong?  Or is there some workaround I can use to get the query to work with the alias?

**edit:** I got it to work correctly by changing the query to:

`SELECT DISTINCT colName1 AS altColName1, colName2 AS altColName2 FROM table`

though I don't understand exactly why this works and the original did not.

Comment: It is hard to suppose what are you doing wrong until you'll show *what exaclty* you're doing. Show your code where you're retrieving data from SqlDataReader.

Comment: Can post your c# code which throw the System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Yeah I apologize I couldn't get the actual C# code.  It's buried in heaps of wrappers we use to build the query, but ultimately the call is to `SqlDataReader.get_Item()` which is in the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You obtain `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` for `colName1` because, using `SELECT` with aliases, the correct name to use is `altColName1`.

So you have to stick to column name or change the code in your `SqlDataReader.get_Item()`.

[`SqlDataReader.Item`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f01t4cfy(v=vs.110).aspx) property gets the value of the specified column in its native format given the column name. So in your code you could find a call like `yourSqlDataReader("colName1")` that don't work if you rename your column as `altColName1`.

Comment: I'm a still a bit confused here.  Why is it that when I run the query in SQL Server Management studio that I use `colName1 AS altColName1` and it doesn't work the other way around.